# How to switch to ipv6 on Linux?

Tags: networking, ipv6

There are many questions on SE and elsewhere about turning off ipv6 on Linux. I want to do the reverse : how can I force the system to use ipv6 as often as possible ?

It's mostly for learning purposes and I must admit I don't know much about ipv6 or networking in general. Ideally, this should not break things and allow programs to switch to ipv4 if necessary.

Comment: If your system has IPv6 connectivity what you describe is the default behaviour. Did you test it and run into problems?

Comment: In my experience, all programs use ipv4 by default even though ipv6 is enabled. I wondered whether I could switch the default to ipv6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable the IPV6 run:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
```

To disable it , run:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

[To check for IPv6 support in the current running kernel](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/ch04s01.html#idp58379504), run:

```
test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo "Running kernel is IPv6 ready"
```

**Edit**

You can easly monitor `IPV6` traffic through [`netdata`](https://github.com/firehol/netdata/wiki/Installation) tool , it can be installed as follows :

```
git clone https://github.com/firehol/netdata.git --depth=1
cd netdata
./netdata-installer.sh
```

Open your browser and type `http://127.0.0.1:19999/` on the address bar .

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be already enabled. Is this all that's needed for programs to be able to use ipv6 ? If I'm on a connection that only allows ipv6, will the system use it ?

Comment: Yes , you can visit http://www.deepspace6.net/docs/ipv6_status_page_apps.html to get some information about the IPv6 Support

Comment: Do you have a globally routable IPv6 address? If you run the command `ip -6 addr`, does it print an address with `scope global`? Linux prefers IPv6 over IPv4, if both can be used.

Comment: I do have a globally routable IPv6 address. Now I'm not sure what protocol is used. Is there a simple way to monitor IPv6 traffic ?

Comment: @YdobEmos Your ISP must provide you with IPv6 service. Unfortunately, some backward ISPs still do not.

Comment: Thank you all, very helpful ! I think I've learned what I wanted.